# How to recieve background notifications in notifee and FCM

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to implement notifications using FCM through rnfirebase in react native.
And to handle the local notifications using notifee.

I have been able to recieve background notifications ie killed state and minimized state through firebase cloud messaging and able to get the foreground notifications using notifee.

Now I want to use notifee for background notifications for consistency betweeen the notifications.

Here the code

```
const displayNotification = async () => {
    const channelId = await notifee.createChannel({
      id: 'important',
      name: 'Important Notifications',
      importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
    });
    notifee.displayNotification({
      body: 'This message was sent via FCM!',
      android: {
        channelId: channelId,
        actions: [
          {
            title: 'Mark as Read',
            pressAction: {
              id: 'read',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    });
  };

   messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
      console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
      displayNotification();
    });

    messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
      console.log('Message handled in the foregourp!', remoteMessage);
      displayNotification();
    });
```

*With this code getting foreground notifications. And when the app is minimized getting two notifications one from notifee and other from FCM. And when the app is killed only getting FCM notification not notifee one.*

**Questions**

1. How to get notification from notifee in killed state ?
2. How to disable FCM background notification. Do I need to send data only notification from firebase ?
3. Also on One Plus device not able to get FCM notification in killed
   state because it is showing that the app is not running. Do I need
   to add a  to the android manifest file ?

**Solution**

Q1 is solved by moving the setBackgroundHandler from inside the useEffect to outside the hook.

Q2 *still pending*

Q3 *still pending*

Answer (score 2):

The backgroundMessageHandler creates a Notification with the Info from FCM on its own and triggering your own would just cause two notifications.
You should remove `displayNotification();` in the backgroundMessageHandler. Further more, the backgroundMessageHandler should be located in `index.js` file and not your App.

Comment: . Yup moving that outside fixed the issue but for double notification I want to disable the FCM notification. Would like to know if there is function for that or do i need to send the message without notification from backend. 
And also if there is anything I can do to make the app run in background and not force stop when removed from recent.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not just an easy parameter to pass to the backgroundMessageHandler to make it stop automatically creating a Push Notification. If you don't want it to create one, don't send notification parameter from backend but just data that contains your notification information and then build your own notification from the data with notifee. Make sure to put the important properties tho or otherwise your data will just be dismissed automatically

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore the FCM background notification, just ignore the notification parameter. Just send the data parameter, but Data-only messages are sent as low priority on both Android and iOS and will not trigger the setBackgroundMessageHandler by default. To enable this functionality, you must set the "priority" to high on Android and enable the content-available flag for iOS in the message payload.

```
{
  "to": "User_Device_Token",
  "data": {
     "body": "Body of Your Notification",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification"
  },
  "priority": "high",
  "contentAvailable": true
}
```

Comment: is that a payload coming from the backend?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the Q2. You need to customise the message object from the backend

**For NodeJS**,

```
import { getMessaging } from "firebase-admin/messaging";

const message = {
    data: {
      title: "Title",
      body: "This is the body",
    },
    token:
      "fcm-token-here",
  };

  getMessaging()
    .send(message)
    .then((response) => {
      res.json({
        msg: "Sent successfully",
      });
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

If you have notification object in the message object it will show the firebase notification too. If you changed it like to data it will not show. You can handle data object from notifee